# Latent Growth Curve Modeling and Model Choice

Tags: panel-data, structural-equation-modeling, clinical-trials, amos

I am running an analysis of a clinical trial dataset. The research question is whether variable y influences the outcomes at each timepoint either as a main effect or in interaction with variable z (treatment). Our statistical consultant suggested that we use SEM and sent a bunch of papers. From his selected literature it seemed like latent growth curve modeling was the best analysis for this question. However, when I tried to model the growth curve (without additional regressors y and z) in SPSS Amos, I got very poor fit statistics and a negative variance estimate for one outcome. My question is: **does it makes sense to use latent growth curve modeling for this dataset or is there a different technique that is more appropriate?** The error messages on AMOS suggested a Heywood case but I am not sure of the solutions there as the n is 22,000 (this is an imputed dataset for intent-to-treat) and there are no additional manifest variables possible. The dataset only contained total scores for the survey, not item-level variables. I am brand new to SEM so I am probably missing something key here and the all-knowing consultant has disappeared, so I appreciate any and all advice.

[image: Diagram without additional regressors y and z]